# Adding fields to user registration form for admins

Tags: 7, entities

I use the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module and I created a registration form for specific events in a Drupal 7 site. For the registered users, the fields are name, surname, birth date, upload administrative files etc.

Is there a way for administrators to have specific fields they can fill and that are not available to registered users?

Comment: you can use markup fields in form,can you tell me which fields type admin can only fill

Comment: An admin can add a checkbox for telling participant was present or not to the event ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hook_form_alter` to accomplish this

```
yourmodule_regform_alter($form, $form_state) {
    global $user;
    if($user->uid!=<whatever>) {
        unset($form['field_attended'];
    }
}
```

If you want to use permissions, you could create your own with `hook_permission`

```
function administer_attendee_permission() {
    return array('set attendee status' => array(
      'title' => t('Set status for event attendees'),
      'description' => t('Set the status for event attendees'),
     );
}
```

Then your form alter changes to

```
yourmodule_regform_alter($form, $form_state) {
    if(!user_access('set attendee status') {
        unset($form['field_attended'];
    }
}
```